# Delete File for particular Month using linux command

Tags: file, centos, delete-file

Below is the file i want to delete and this fall under january month.

How to delete the january month file?
Let me know if this command can be use

```
rm -r 2020-01*.csv
```

i want to delete only `.csv` and not the `targz` file

Tar File

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 252611170 Jul 23 17:33 2020-01-11-15Jan.tar.gz
```

File

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 373401287 Jan 31 23:58 2020-01-31-22-58-39.done.csv


-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 386130576 Feb  1 00:58 2020-01-31-23-58-39.done.csv
```

Comment: Duplicate. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618543/9790416

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete multiple files at once in Bash on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516384/how-to-delete-multiple-files-at-once-in-bash-on-linux)